# Main page still shows the name of last poster even after he deletes his post

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

For example, in this question [How to allow letters only in VARCHAR2 column (Oracle SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703598/how-to-allow-letters-only-in-varchar2-column-oracle-sql) there was another answer posted by Alex Poole after my answer. Afterwards, he deleted his answer since it was sort of duplicate.

However, the main page still shows his name along with the topic title, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle

I understand that a deleted post is not actually permanently deleted, but stays unseen by other members, and only the poster can see it.

But the name shown beside the topic title in the main page is somewhat misleading. In the example shown, the entire thread doesn't show that posters name or contribution, but the main page is showing up. It is not going to hamper anything, I just had an observation.

Comment: @rene, I see. It would be consuming a lot, I mean really a lot of hardware and resources.

Comment: @rene actually it's not cache, it would still show the name even years after deletion. But no worry, I fell for the same trap myself year and half ago. :D

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I'm missing something but I don't think caching is the issue here. The "modified [time]" with the user name that is displayed in those lists indicates who last modified the *group* of question + answers. Any edit to any of the posts will count as a change. A deletion also counts as a change. So I think Alex Poole will remain shown there until another modification is made by someone else.

Comment: And I believe, by modification you mean a new answer and not just an edit to an existing answer.

Comment: @LalitKumarB A new answer is a modification, and an edit to an existing answer is a modification.

Comment: @ShadowWizard where would we all be without your knowledge....

Comment: Oops, I mean editing the question won't effect it. I agree, making an edit to an existing answer is a modification with respect to my concern.

Comment: @rene http://i.stack.imgur.com/wQrG1.jpg (duh! ;))

Comment: @rene, without shadowwizard's knowledge, I believe we would witness more amount of caching. As he marked the topic duplicate, thus decreasing the usage of resources :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I couldn't find my answer in the link you posted as a duplicate...

Comment: @Lalit well, it is implied that having the answer deleted doesn't cause the main page to show the previous activity, i.e. this is by design.

Comment: Got it! It is by design...